# Find how much time exists within two unix timestamps

Tags: php, logic

I need to find how many seconds exist between two different unix timestamps within a certain range.

For example:

Travel Start: 05:00
Site Arrival: 07:00
Standby Hours: 06:00 - 09:00

I need to find how many seconds the user is traveling and how many seconds he spends on standby.

The above result should output:

```
Travel = 3600 seconds (05:00 - 06:00)
Standby = 3600 seconds (06:00 - 07:00)
```

Another example:

Travel Start: 10:00
Site Arrival: 11:30
Standby Hours: 06:00 - 09:00

```
Travel = 5400 seconds (10:00 - 11:30)
Standby = 0 seconds
```

Example code which I do not think is correct:

```
if($travel_start_time >= $standby_start_time)
{
    if($first_site_arrival <= $standby_end_time)
    {
        $travel_during_standby = max($first_site_arrival-$travel_start_time, 0);
    }
    elseif($first_site_arrival >= $standby_end_time)
    {
        $travel_during_standby = max($first_site_arrival-$standby_end_time, 0);
    }
}
else
{
    $travel_during_standby = max($first_site_arrival-$standby_start_time, 0);
}
```

Comment: What did you try? You don't even need unix timestamps, you can just use **strtotime** to subtract the times between them.

Comment: I'm already using strtotime,

Comment: This is the code i'm using but i'm not sure the logic makes sense.  Please assume the values are already in strtotime format. http://pastebin.com/n6DF3Dw7

Comment: I just updated the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're asking '**How much time is common to two possibly overlapping Unix timestamp ranges ?**'
From a 'Logic' point of view...
Given that your times are already converted into Unix timestamps, as T1 and T2 for travel, and S1 and S2 for standby.
Travel time is `T2-T1`
Standby time is `S2-S1`
There will be an overlap if `((S1<T2) && (S2>T1))`
If there's an overlap,then the travel during standby will be `(Min(T2,S2) - Max(T1,S1))`

Translating the logic into PHP is fairly straightforward...

```
$travel_during_standby = ((($standby_start_time < $travel_end_time)&&($standby_end_time > $travel_start_time)))? (Min($travel_end_time,$standby_end_time) - Max($travel_start_time,$standby_start_time)) : 0;
```

An alternative blunter approach would be to blindly calculate the overlap and ignore any negative results...

```
$travel_during_standby = Max( (Min($travel_end_time,$standby_end_time) - Max($travel_start_time,$standby_start_time)) , 0 );
```

Comment: Gavin, would you be willing to take a look at our code?

Comment: @V4n1ll4, that's a vague request... In what capacity ?

Comment: we are struggling with the logic in one of our applications, would you be interested in taking a look?